# focus and (focus out) at the same time using jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to protect my inputs from brut force hacks
so i made some validations for my inputs .. and i want them to work on focus event and
focusout event too ! is there any elegant way to do it, other than this :

```
$(this).focus(function(){
// excute my code
});
```

and then

```
$(this).focusout(function(){
// excute the same code !
});
```

i want do this for too many inputs .. and i don't want do the same work twice for (focus, and focusout) to avoid the extra load of the page !

Comment: You can't use JavaScript to stop brute force attacks. The attacker can just disable (or modify) JavaScript.

Comment: i supported my inputs with javascript validation just as a "first level validation"
i will do another "server side" validation using PHP or ASP .. i just don't want everything to be done with only PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I disagree with the premise of this question (you can't prevent brute-force attacks via client-side code) you can simplify your code by passing both events as a space separated string to [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(this).on('focus focusout', function() {
    // excute my code
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bL79F/

---

If you're using an older version of jQuery, use [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) instead:

```
$(this).bind('focus focusout', function() {
    // excute my code
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bL79F/1/

Comment: @user1283226 - what version of jQuery do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function once, and use it wherever you need

```
function validate(){
   // validation code
}

$(this).on('focus focusout', validate );
```

But any client-side validation is bound to be overriden ...
You will **need** to have server-side validation..

---

For earlier versions of jQuery use

```
$(this).bind('focus focusout', validate );
```

Comment: yes i know .. i'll do some validation through PHP or ASP as well  
but your code is not working ! sorry .. can you provide me with some simple jsfiddle working example ?

Answer (score 0):

As everyone is saying, you need server side validation regardless.  I'm not sure whether jQuery converts `focusin` and `focusout` to `focus` and `blur`, but I imagine it does.

Newer versions:

```
$(this).on('focusin focusout focus blur', function () {
```

older versions just replace `.on` with `.bind` and it should work the same